# Get quantity in numeric or written form before a substring in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, substring

I have a large string, `$string`, in which I am trying to see if a the quantity of a certain item, "game", is mentioned.

For example:

```
$string = "...asdasda fdf **4 games** asdasd sad ...";
```

OR

```
$string = "...asdasda fdf **nine games** asdasd sad ..."; 
//maximum is around 15 but till about 10 should be enough for now
```

OR

```
$string = "...asdasda fdf asdasd sad **a game** asda ...";
```

"game" might appear more than once in `$string`.
if "game" always appears in it's singular form ("game" and not "games") then the quantity is 1.

The quantity associated with any one of "games"'s occurrences should be the same as it will be talking about the same number of "games" even though it may not always mention the quantity, so any quantity before "games" should give the correct amount.

How would I best go about doing this in php. Any pregmatch, or regular expression would help as I understand it but am not that good with it.

I guess maybe taking the word before and then checking it for a number might work using a regex with sub string `str_pos`, followed by a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
\w+(?=\sgames?)
```

for capturing the quantity that is given in numbers or letters.

You can write a function to convert the string quantity to numerical quantity if need be.

[Working example of the regex on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lV1zU6).

Comment: Sorry could you break this down a bit for me. From looking at it, it finds the word prior to the word game (with one white space before the word game). Is that all it does? How does it deal with the quantity of the word game appearing in the string? Do I then have to possible create a function which takes all the instances individually and then when it finds a match to a quantity other than say "1" or "a" get that quantity and break- otherwise assume the quantity is one?

Comment: @Sortitout Yes, that is what it does. You can capture numbers and calculate them easily, but you need to convert the words to numbers using a function. You might find such a function online if you Google it.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Although my custom function to get the numeric value is a bit wordy :P